# fast string search to find string array element which matches the givven pattern

Tags: c, fastsearch

I have an array of constant strings which I iterate through to find an index of element which is a string that contains a search pattern. Which search algorithm should I choose to improve the speed of finding this element? I am not limited in time before running the application for preparing the look up tables if any are necessary.

I corrected a question - I am not doing exact string match - I am searching for pattern inside the element, which is in an array

```
array of strings:
[0] Red fox jumps over the fence
[1] Blue table
[2] Red flowers on the fence
```

I need to find an element which contains word 'table' - in this case its element 1

I do like 50000 iterations of a set of 30 array which could contain up to 30000 strings of not less than 128 characters. Now I am using good-old `strstr` brute force which is too slow...

Ok, posting a part of my function, the first `strstr` - looks up in an uncut array of lines if there are any occurrences, then the brute search follows. I know I can speed this part, but I am not doing optimization on this approach...

```
// sheets[i].buffer - contains a page of a text which is split into lines
// fullfunccall - is the pattern
// sheets[i].cells[k] - are the pointers to lines in a buffer

for (i = 0; i < sheetcount; i++) {
    if (i != currsheet && sheets[i].name && sheets[i].name[0] != '\0') {
        if (strstr(sheets[i].buffer, fullfunccall)) {
            usedexternally = 1;

            int foundatleastone = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < sheets[i].numcells; k++) {
                strncpy_s(testline, MAX_LINE_SIZE,
                          sheets[i].cells[k]->line,
                          sheets[i].cells[k]->linesize);
                testline[sheets[i].cells[k]->linesize] = '\0';

                if (strstr(testline, fullfunccall)) {
                    dependency_num++;

                    if (dependency_num >= MAX_CELL_DEPENDENCIES-1) {
                        printf("allocation for sheet cell dependencies is insufficient\n");
                        return;
                    }

                    sheets[currsheet].cells[currcellposinsheet]->numdeps = dependency_num + 1;
                    foundatleastone++;
                    sheets[currsheet].cells[currcellposinsheet]->deps[dependency_num] = &sheets[i].cells[k];
                }
            }

            if (foundatleastone == 0) {
                printf("error locating dependency for external func: %s\n", fullfunccall);
                return;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @DoomProg 30000 elements with some 200character strings

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking. Could you please give an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: @MOehm I edited the question which contains an example

Comment: You can use strtok() for each array[i] and search in it the word you want with srtcmp() . I do not see another way. You can see this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: @DoomProg thanks, I already do that and its ```SLOW```

Comment: Thanks. You are always looking for whole words, right? So, "able" shouldn't match anything. And are you looking for any or all matches, i.e should a search for "fence" result in just 0 or in (0, 2)?

Comment: @MOehm I am matching with strstr - exact match, not whole words. fence in this case would give out 0 and 2

Comment: Could you please post your `strstr` code as reference implementation? That would be very helpful. (I'm afrraid that I still don't know what you want exactly.)

Comment: Do you know anything about the patterns (`table`, in your example) which you're looking for? Is there a minimum and/or maximum length to them? Do you expect to get certain kinds of patterns (e.g. whole words such as `table` or `fence`) more often than others (e.g. single letters or fragments like `ver the`)?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe yes, I am aware of everything, so in my case the input is usually either 5 characters, or 20 characters and they can appear anywhere in the line. Separators are not used to delimit anything

Answer (score 2):

You wrote that your 'haystack' (the set of strings to search through) is roughly 30000 strings with approx. 200 characters each. You also wrote that the 'needle' (the term to search for) is either a string of 5 or 20 characters.

Based on this, you could precompute a hashtable which maps any 5-character subsequence to the string(s) in the haystack it occurs in. For 30000 strings (200 characters each) there are at most 30000 * (200 - 5) = 5.850.000 different 5-character substrings. If you hash each of it to a 16bit checksum you'd need a minimum 11MB of memory (for the hash keys) plus some pointers pointing to the string(s) in which the substring occurs.

For instance, given a simplfied haystack of

```
static const char *haystack[] = { "12345", "123456", "23456", "345678" };
```

you precompute a hash map which maps any possible 5-character string such that

```
12345 => haystack[0], haystack[1]
23456 => haystack[1], haystack[2]
34567 => haystack[3]
45678 => haystack[4]
```

With this, you could take the first five characters of your given key (either 5 or 20 characters long), hash it and then do a normal `strstr` through all the strings to which the key is mapped by the hash.

Comment: I'll definitely try that

Answer (score 2):

For each sheet that you are treating, you could build a suffix array as described in [this article](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/sec152.html). Before you start your search, read the sheet, find the line beginnings (as integer indices into the sheet buffer), create the suffix array and sort it as described in the article.

Now, if you are looking for the lines in which a pattern, say "table", occurs, you can search for the next entry after "table" and the next entry after "tablf", which is the first non-match, where you have moved the right-most letter, odometer-style.

If both indices are the same, there are no matches. If they are different, you'll get a list of pointers into the sheet:

```
"tab. And now ..."
----------------------------------------------------------------
"table and ..."                0x0100ab30
"table water for ..."          0x0100132b
"tablet computer ..."          0x01000208
----------------------------------------------------------------
"tabloid reporter ..."
```

This will give you a list of pointers from which, by subtracting the base pointer of the sheet buffer, you can get the integer offsets. Comparison with the line beginnings will give you the line numbers that correspond to these pointers. (The line numbers are sorted, so you can do binary search here.)

The memory overhead is an array of pointers that has the same size as the sheet buffer, so for 30,000 strings of 200 chars, that will be about 48MB on a 64-bit machine. (The overhead of the line indices is negligible.)

Sorting the array will take long, but it is done only once for each sheet.

**Edit**: The idea seems to work well. I have implemented it and can scan a dictionary of about 130,000 words on a [text file of nearly 600k](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1661/pg1661.txt) in less then one second:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define die(...) exit((fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: " __VA_ARGS__), \
    putc(10, stderr), 1))



typedef struct Sheet Sheet;    

struct Sheet {
    size_t size;    /* Number of chars */
    char *buf;      /* Null-terminated char buffer */
    char **ptr;     /* Pointers into char buffer */
    size_t nline;   /* number of lines */
    int *line;      /* array of offset of line beginnings */
    size_t naux;    /* size of scratch array */
    char **aux;     /* scratch array */
};


/*
 *      Count occurrence of c in zero-terminated string p.
 */
size_t strcount(const char *p, int c)
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for (;;) {
        p = strchr(p, c);
        if (p == NULL) return n;
        p++;
        n++;        
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
 *      String comparison via pointers to strings.
 */
int pstrcmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char *const *aa = a;
    const char *const *bb = b;

    return strcmp(*aa, *bb);
}

/*
 *      Pointer comparison.
 */
int ptrcmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char *const *aa = a;
    const char *const *bb = b;

    if (*aa == *bb) return 0;   
    return (*aa < *bb) ? -1 : 1;
}

/*
 *      Create and prepare a sheet, i.e. a text file to search.
 */
Sheet *sheet_new(const char *fn)
{
    Sheet *sheet;
    FILE *f = fopen(fn, "r");
    size_t n;
    int last;
    char *p;
    char **pp;

    if (f == NULL) die("Couldn't open %s", fn);

    sheet = malloc(sizeof(*sheet));
    if (sheet == NULL) die("Allocation failed");

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    sheet->size = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    sheet->buf = malloc(sheet->size + 1);
    sheet->ptr = malloc(sheet->size * sizeof(*sheet->ptr));

    if (sheet->buf == NULL) die("Allocation failed");
    if (sheet->ptr == NULL) die("Allocation failed");

    fread(sheet->buf, 1, sheet->size, f);
    sheet->buf[sheet->size] = '\0';
    fclose(f);

    sheet->nline = strcount(sheet->buf, '\n');
    sheet->line = malloc(sheet->nline * sizeof(*sheet->line));

    sheet->aux = NULL;
    sheet->naux = 0;

    n = 0;
    last = 0;
    p = sheet->buf;
    pp = sheet->ptr;
    while (*p) {
        *pp++ = p;
        if (*p == '\n') {
            sheet->line[n++] = last;
            last = p - sheet->buf + 1;
        }
        p++;
    }

    qsort(sheet->ptr, sheet->size, sizeof(*sheet->ptr), pstrcmp);

    return sheet;
}

/*
 *      Clean up sheet.
 */
void sheet_delete(Sheet *sheet)
{
    free(sheet->buf);
    free(sheet->ptr);
    free(sheet->line);
    free(sheet->aux);
    free(sheet);
}

/*
 *      Binary range search for string pointers.
 */
static char **pstr_bsearch(const char *key,
    char **arr, size_t high)
{
    size_t low = 0;

    while (low < high) {
        size_t mid = (low + high) / 2;
        int diff = strcmp(key, arr[mid]);

        if (diff < 0) high = mid;
        else low = mid + 1;
    }

    return arr + low;
}

/*
 *      Binary range search for line offsets.
 */
static const int *int_bsearch(int key, const int *arr, size_t high)
{
    size_t low = 0;

    while (low < high) {
        size_t mid = (low + high) / 2;
        int diff = key - arr[mid];

        if (diff < 0) high = mid;
        else low = mid + 1;
    }

    if (low < 1) return NULL;
    return arr + low - 1;
}

/*
 *      Find occurrences of the string key in the sheet. Returns the
 *      number of lines in which the key occurs and assigns up to
 *      max lines to the line array. (If max is 0, line may be NULL.)
 */
int sheet_find(Sheet *sheet, char *key,
    int line[], int max)
{
    char **begin, **end;
    int n = 0;
    size_t i, m;
    size_t last;

    begin = pstr_bsearch(key, sheet->ptr, sheet->size);
    if (begin == NULL) return 0;

    key[strlen(key) - 1]++;
    end = pstr_bsearch(key, sheet->ptr, sheet->size);
    key[strlen(key) - 1]--;
    if (end == NULL) return 0;
    if (end == begin) return 0;

    m = end - begin;
    if (m > sheet->naux) {
        if (sheet->naux == 0) sheet->naux = 0x100;
        while (sheet->naux < m) sheet->naux *= 2;
        sheet->aux = realloc(sheet->aux, sheet->naux * sizeof(*sheet->aux));
        if (sheet->aux == NULL) die("Re-allocation failed");        
    }

    memcpy(sheet->aux, begin, m * sizeof(*begin));
    qsort(sheet->aux, m, sizeof(*begin), ptrcmp);

    last = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int offset = sheet->aux[i] - sheet->buf;
        const int *p;

        p = int_bsearch(offset, sheet->line + last, sheet->nline - last);

        if (p) {
            if (n < max) line[n] = p - sheet->line;
            last = p - sheet->line + 1;
            n++;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

/*
 *      Example client code
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Sheet *sheet;
    FILE *f;

    if (argc != 3) die("Usage: %s patterns corpus", *argv);

    sheet = sheet_new(argv[2]);

    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (f == NULL) die("Can't open %s.", argv[1]);
    for (;;) {
        char str[80];
        int line[50];
        int i, n;

        if (fgets(str, sizeof(str), f) == NULL) break;
        strtok(str, "\n");
        n = sheet_find(sheet, str, line, 50);
        printf("%8d %s\n", n, str);

        if (n > 50) n = 50;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("    [%d] %d\n", i, line[i] + 1);
    }
    fclose(f);

    sheet_delete(sheet);

    return 0;
}
```

The implementation has its rough edges, but it works. I'm not especially fond of the scratch array and the additional sorting on the found pointer range, but it turns out that even sorting the large suffix array doesn't take too long.

You can extend this solution to more sheets, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most practical would be DFA as it reads every character of input at most once - more precisely it reads every input char once and stops as soon as pattern will not match definitely (if set up properly). With DFA you can also check against multiple patterns simultaneously.

Two good (but different) implementations of DFA algorithms well tested in practice are

- [PIRE](https://github.com/yandex/pire)
- [Ragel](http://www.colm.net/open-source/ragel/)

It's not possible say which fits your task unless you provide more on that.

edit: DFA stays for "Deterministic Finite Automata"

edit: as you indicated your patterns are exact substrings the most common solution is [KMP](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-for-patterns-set-2-kmp-algorithm/) algorithm (Knuth-Morris-Pratt)

Comment: I do like 50000 iterations of a set of 30 array which could contain up to 30000 strings of not less than 128 characters

Comment: If you 50000 iterations means 50000 static search patterns then DFA is absolute winner as you can unite many patterns into single iteration. PIRE is designed for that specially while Ragel can handle this also with some help from you (ie generating source in its input language)

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I expect some 3 or 4 functions for this job, not a library, but I will have a look

Comment: DFA is the way to go; once constructed it will need only one pass on the input file. It is like finding multiple pins in a single haystack.

Comment: Ragel is a program (not a library) that will generate you a function in C that you can just link against